# How to put multiple time series lines on one graph in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I have data where I am looking at seed germination rates and comparing 2 different treatment phases and seed sources. Each of the 2 phases has multiple groups. I am trying to graph the results as a time series or at least look similar to a time series. The data I have looks like this:

| Source | Phase 1 | Phase 2 | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 4 | 4 | 8 |
| 1 | A | Y | 0 | 17 | 17 |
| 1 | A | Z | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| 1 | B | X | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | B | Y | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | B | Z | 0 | 5 | 8 |

I have tried converting the data into long form and grouping the day columns using the pivot_longer and names_to functions and then tried graphing using the following code:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x= days_num, y = germination, group=phase 1))+
  geom_line(aes(color=phase 2)) +
  facet_grid(source~.)
```

It gives me a graph like this:[image: R generated graph]

The following image is along the lines of what I would like it to look like: [image: time series graph]

I'd like to be able to have my different sources in graphs side by side, and then have my phase 1 (A - XYZ) lines as one graph and (B - XYZ) separate.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mapping `phase 1` to group, you are mapping 2 values to each of 3 different phases 2. Map phase 2 to color and facet the plot by phase 1 instead.

```r
df1 <- "Source  'Phase 1'   'Phase 2'   'Day 1'     'Day 2'     'Day 3'
1   A   X   4   4   8
1   A   Y   0   17  17
1   A   Z   5   10  15
1   B   X   2   4   6
1   B   Y   1   2   3
1   B   Z   0   5   8"
df1 <- read.table(text = df1, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Day"), names_to = "day_num", values_to = "germination") %>%
  mutate(day_num = stringr::str_extract(day_num, "\\d+"),
         day_num = as.integer(day_num)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(day_num, germination, color = `Phase 2`)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Day", y = "Germination") +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(`Phase 1`)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Note:** The plot above does not use `Source` because the posted data example only has one source. If there are sources more it might be an option to instead facet with

```
facet_grid(`Phase 1` ~ Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `matplot` in `base R`

```
 par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
 lst1 <- split(df1[-(1:2)], df1$"Phase 1")
 Map(\(x, nm) {
     colrs <- rainbow(nrow(x))
     matplot(`colnames<-`(t(x[-1]), x[[1]]), type = "l", 
  ylab = "Germination", main = nm, col = colrs, lty = "solid", lwd = 1.5)
      legend("right", legend = x$"Phase 2", lty=c(1,1, 1),
     lwd=c(1.5,1.5, 1.5), col = colrs)
     
     }, lst1, names(lst1))
```

-output

[image]